# ConnectionString issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure-storage, entity-framework-4.3

I am having an issue with my connectionString in a MVC 4 project.

The project is structured the following way:

```
Solution
   -MVC4-web app project
   -Custom DBContext project
   -Portable Area project (MvcContrib)
```

I am using an online Azure database for the storage, and all my models are in the custom db context. The project compiles find, and I have even got MvcContrib to work with MVC4 and Razor view engine.

After creating a new DB on Azure i try to run update-database on the DBContext project. I get the following error:

> "... An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. ...  provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified ..."

My connectionString is in the App.Config file in the DbContext project:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="CortexModelContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=tcp:k5bqinuyr5.database.windows.net,1433;Database=databaseName;User ID=myname@k5bqinuyr5;Password=MySecretPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

What am I doing wrong? I have duodecuple-checked the password, and the connection string. It is a copy-paste from the portal on windowsazure.com. What else can be wrong here? I feel like I have tried everything to fix this issue.

If there is some other information lacking from this post, please tell me and I will provide it.

Comment: Have you configured the Azure firewall to allow access from the location you are running the project?

Comment: Yes. I made that mistake once before. Hehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have your context in a separate project the Update-Database command doesn't tend to work properly. Presumably you have your connection string in your MVC 4 project's web.config file as well?

If so use the following command:

```
Update-Database -ProjectName <DbContextProject> -StartupProjectName <MvcProject>
```

replacing the placeholders with the names of the relevant projects. That should do the job.

Cheers,
Dean

Comment: Same thing happened now. I used the following command: "Update-Database -ProjectName MyNamespace.Subspace.Model -StartupProjectName TheMvcProject". Am I supposed to have the brackets?

Comment: Nope, no brackets. The -ProjectName bit should be just the name of the project containing the DbContext. If you use the -verbose option it should let you know what server it's actually trying to connect to. That'll give you a hint as to whether it's using the right one or not!

Comment: I have now tried a lot of different combinations here.. Could you maybe write out the entire command with the model project name being "MyNamespace.Subspace.Model" and the startup project name being "TheMvcProject"?

Comment: Sure thing... `Update-Database -ProjectName MyNamespace.Subspace.Model -StartupProjectName TheMvcProject -Verbose`

Comment: I get output like this as the first line... `Target database is: 'MyDb' (DataSource: localhost, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: UserCode).`

Comment: What was the first line of output - did it give you the right target database?

Comment: I figured it out now. I had conflicting web.config files

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that I did not have the connection string in all my projects. When I added the connection string, that was currently only in my DbContext project's App.config, to the `web.config` of the startup project everything worked.

Good thing I didn't use a whole day to figure that out, or something.

Comment: That's what I said in the first line of my answer! Glad you fixed it :)